# Java Script Vat Calculate Function correctly not calculate

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im try to write **JavaScript** Vat calculate **vat value in 15%** actually its not correctly calculate how can i fix it,

---

Gross  Amount   =9000
VAT(+)% = 15%
1350

---

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        //Vat Calculate
        $(function () {

            $('#txtGrossAmount').on('input', function () {
                calculate();
            });
            $('#txtVatno').on('input', function () {
                calculate();
            });
            function calculate() {
                var pPos = parseInt($('#txtGrossAmount').val());
                var pEarned = parseInt($('#txtVatno').val());
                var perc = "";
                if (isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)) {
                    perc = " ";
                } else {
                    perc = ((pEarned / pPos) * 100).toFixed(3);
                }

                $('#txtTax').val(perc);
            }

        });
</script>
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:55px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Gross Amount" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossAmount" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control boxDisable"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="VAT(15%)" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label26" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVatno" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control boxDisable"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">

            <asp:Label ID="lblTax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control boxDisable"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER , can you please explain the reason for your vote :)

Comment: try changing this `perc = ((pEarned / pPos) * 100).toFixed(3);` to `perc = ((pPos / 100) * pEarned).toFixed(3);`

Comment: Thanks Sir, Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

It is working
**ASP.NET**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="VAT(15%)" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label26" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVatno" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control boxDisable"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">

            <asp:Label ID="lblTax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:5px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control boxDisable"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {

$('#txtGrossAmount').on('input', function () {
    calculate();
});
$('#txtVatno').on('input', function () {
    calculate();
});
function calculate() {
    var PPos = parseInt($('#txtGrossAmount').val());
    var PEarned = parseInt($('#txtVatno').val());
    var perc = "";
    if (isNaN(PPos) || isNaN(PEarned)) {
        perc = " ";
    } else {
        perc = ((PPos / 100) * PEarned).toFixed(3);
    }

    $('#txtTax').val(perc);
}
```

});